# Логическая операция

Tags: php, логика

Как составить выражение в операторе if c &&, чтобы проверялось каждое выражение, а не только первая часть?
if (false && true) - проверяет только первую часть и выдаёт false. Допустим:

```
if (empty($login) && empty($email)) {$error = 'Поля не должны быть пустыми.';}
```

При заполненном логине и пустом емейле - выдаёт false. Как написать, чтобы и логин и емейл проверялись?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так нужно ИЛИ использовать))

```
if (empty($login) || empty($email)) {$error = 'Поля не должны быть пустыми.';}
```

Comment: Вот я туплю!)) Спасибо

Comment: @Vlad, если ответ решил проблему, и он Вас устраивает, закройте вопрос

Comment: Сейчас разберусь, как тут закрывать))

Answer (score 2):

Позвольте, внесу свою лепту.
В PHP `0, NULL, EMPTY, ""` в IF возвращает FALSE, поэтому упрощаем:

```
if( !$login || !$email ) $error = 'Поля не должны быть пустыми.';
```

Comment: Век живи - век учись)) Спасибо